# What would happen if gen-class was called twice in repl mode?

Tags: clojure

The code for `gen-class` looks like this:

```
(when *compile-files*
  (let [options-map (into1 {} (map vec (partition 2 options)))
        [cname bytecode] (generate-class options-map)]
    (clojure.lang.Compiler/writeClassFile cname bytecode)))
```

What would happen if `*compile-files*` flag was bound to true and gen-class was called twice when in repl mode?

Comment: Try it out and let us know.

Comment: @amalloy, it generates the class twice. I'm more wondering if there was a particular reason why definterface is not compile only whilst gen-class is.